# Django + uWSGI + Nginx returns 403 Forbidden when using HTTPS

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, uwsgi

I'm writing a RESTful server application using Django 1.7.7 and Django REST framework. The application has been working perfectly when I've run it on the Django test server.

Now, I deployed it to a staging server on AWS running Nginx and uWSGI. The server seems to be running otherwise fine, but calling a POST method causes a "403 Forbidden" response. If I disable HTTPS, the call works just fine, so it has got something to do with the HTTPS.

Here's my Nginx config file for the site:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name <HERE'S MY SERVER ADDRESS>;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.key;
    ssl_ciphers 'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT myapp.wsgi;
        uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        uwsgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        uwsgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
    }
}
```

To reiterate, if I change `listen 443 ssl` to `listen 80 default_server` and change `ssl on` to `ssl off`, the POST methods work just as they should.

Here's the uWSGI config file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /web/myapp/source/myapp
module = myapp.wsgi
```

One thing I suspect is that the CSRF header gets stripped off somewhere before it reachers Django's CSRF middleware, but I don't know how to verify this. It could be something completely different, too.

Comment: If you turn Django debug on, do you get a 403 from Nginx or from Django? What does you Nginx logs say? In case of a CSRF error you will get a an error from Django.

Comment: @het.oosten It seems the POST never reaches Django, at least the logs do not indicate that they would go to Django. Nginx access log says pretty much just 403 Forbidden, and error log is empty.

Comment: looks really strange. try removing everything that you don't really need for testing, like all of the `uwsgi_param` directives (leaving only `include uwsgi_params`), the extra headers, and ssl encryption settings and see if it changes anything

Comment: also it might be useful to see your uWSGI configuration. and did you verify that setting DEBUG=True in Django doesn't help to get a meaningful error message?

Comment: Check that Django `ALLOWED_HOSTS` works with the config. This settings might cause 403 Forbidden. Also in this case requests are not logged by Django, usually.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev Disabling just SSL and enabling port 80 causes everything to work correctly, although without encryption, which has to be enforced on this site. I added the uWSGI config file to the post. Django doesn't really tell anything meaningful; the log file stays empty.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa The ALLOWED_HOSTS includes only `localhost`. Should it be different in this case?

Comment: Try adding the same as `server_name` in Nginx, then make sure you forward Host header correctly. Don't remember if `Host` needed additional setup with uWSGI - with some servers it did.

Comment: @manabreak if you have DEBUG=False, you should set ALLOWED_HOSTS to include your real hostname. That's why I asked if setting DEBUG=True changes anything. But it's strange that switching off ssl makes it work.

Comment: Have you read this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I set the server name to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but nothing changed. I don't really know how to set up the host header forwarding you mentioned.

Comment: @manabreak the host header forwarding is already included in `include uwsgi_params`. Did you try removing all the unnecessary settings as I said earlier?